# Unwrapping a model "loosely" with each face separate?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a... weird mesh. It doesn't look that weird, but it makes the automatic unwrapping in Blender do weird things. It stretches and distorts the texture; it does all kinds of things.

This mesh, however, contains not many faces. Pretty much, each of them are rectangular, with maybe a dozen or so triangles.

That's why, I'd like to unwrap it in a way so every face is separate.[image: Left side is how unwrapping works now, right side is how I'd like it to work.]

The left side shows how unwrapping works now, the right side is how I'd like it to work. Forgive me the Paint picture, but I didn't deem it necessary to launch something more powerful for just a rough sketch.

Do I just manually mark every edge as a seam, or is it a hidden, existing function somewhere?

Comment: Use [Smart UV Project](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/texturing/unwrapping.html#smart-uv-project) UV mapping to make islands being different. However it's strange simple mesh gives unexpected results when unwrapped; could it be that you [pinned](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/texturing/layout_editing.html#pinning) certain UV vertices ?

Comment: I mainly mean it, as in the sizes and aspect ratio of the faces is, well, very varied. For example in [this](http://i.imgur.com/qBjmOVW.png) picture the elements in red circles are supposed to be doorways, and are supposed to be **the same size**.

The texture is in 4096x4096, but still, if I painted on this image, one wall would have vastly different resolution from another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Smart Unwrapping with the angle set to minimum. There wasn't even any need to mark seams, **seam** like it (heh).

The Smart Unwrap settings I used:
[image: Smart Unwrap settings]]

It's all about that angle limit, that's the setting that makes each face a separate island. Unchecking stretching to UV bounds makes the faces keep aspect ratio. Island margin can be there, or it can be set to 0, it's all up to your personal preference.

Here's how it looks on a simple cube:
[image: Smart Unwrap of a cube]

Comment: stack exchange does not work like a forum. The answer are not meant as a reply, but to answer the question (answering your own question is fine). Please edit your answer to elaborate on what you did that worked(maybe a screen shot of the unwrap settings).

Comment: Is the way it looks now acceptable? added two screenshots, one of settings I used, and one of the final result.

Comment: Much better, nice answer. Please have a look at how I [edited](http://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/50550/revisions) your answer to get an idea of what you can do in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: Mark all edges as seams and then unwrap.

Answer (score 0):

or use the **UV unwrap -> lightmap pack** option instead of the regular unwrap.